# Can't add share title on IOS in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have to integrate the Share API in my app and on Android works ok but on IOS the message is always shared as title so what I add on title is ignored.

React Native version:

```
System:
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.4
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 533.27 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 8.3.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.3.0/bin/node
Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 5.3.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.3.0/bin/npm
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
Xcode: 11.2/11B52 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.4 => 0.61.4
```

Steps To Reproduce

1. Add title and message in share content
2. See that on IOS the message is always added both as title and message and title is not used at all

Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository:

```
const shareContentAndroid = {
  title: productInfo,
  message: shareMessage
};
const shareContentIOS = {
  title: 'Share via',
  message: productInfo, //title
  url: null
};
let shareContent = IfAndroid(shareContentAndroid, shareContentIOS);
let shareOptions = {
  dialogTitle: 'dialog title',
  subject: 'subject'
}
Share.share(shareContent, shareOptions);
```

Comment: Can you paste the `IfAndroid` function please?

Comment: export function IfAndroid(androidStyle, iosStyle) {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      return androidStyle;
  }
  return iosStyle;
}